# Set address model in library name while building boost

Tags: boost, boost-build

I want to build boost in both 32 and 64 bit. I can build them separately by using `address-model=64` option in command line while building them in 64 bit.

I've noticed that there's no difference in library names when they are built for different architectures (i.e. `libboost_wserialization-vc120-sgd-1_60.lib` remain the same in 32 bit and 64 bit).

Is there a way to make library names different when building with `address-model=64` option?

I'd like to have something like `libboost_wserialization-vc120-x64-sgd-1_60.lib` or something similar.

Comment: Check `boostcpp.jam` -- perhaps you could modify the **tag** rule to included the `<address-model>`?

Comment: FYI, I had a similar goal and I ended up solving it [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42408982/43534).